# Flink: How to handle Null Values in Flink especially while reading a file like csv

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

Flink: How to handle Null Values in Flink especially while reading a file  like CSV.

I come from spark back ground. So there is null handling in spark. like df.na.fill etc.

So I was wondering if there is any such facility in Dataset API or the only way is to do it map function.

Also is it better to use POJO instead of Case Class? Will the default values initiated in POJO take effect while the value is missing in the data file.

Comment: have you tried .filter(value -> (value != null)) ?

Comment: What's your specific question?

Comment: @ArvidHeise. I have edited the question hope it is clear enough as to what my query is.